# Passing Username from one JFRAME to Another Using MYSQL in NetBeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am trying to get the username used to login so as to create a query for that specific user under MySQL. With that query i will be able to display all data from that specific row. i.e From this Dashboard i am supposed to display the name of the user who logged in.

I tried to do the following and this was the result. We have the login, Dashboard and the output results.

From the output, `getUsername()` is null from the Dashboard side unlike from the login side.

I tried using an array to store the string though it ended up destroying it and becoming null.

What could be the problem?

**Login**

```
            if(rs.next())
            {
                StudentHomeDashboard studentHomeDashboard = new StudentHomeDashboard();

                loginDetails = rs.getString("RegNO");
                
                setUsername(loginDetails);
                System.out.println("Username : " + getUsername());

                //Correct details
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Logged In!");
               
                
                //close login form
                this.setVisible(false);
                this.dispose();
                
                studentHomeDashBoard.show();
            }
            else
            {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID DETAILS!"); 
               
               //clear the form automatically
                usernameField.setText("");
                passwordField.setText("");
            }
```

**DashBoard**

```
//GET NAME, YEAR, SCHOOL, PROGRAMME
    try 
        {
            StudentLogin login = new StudentLogin();

            //Fetch Values for the specific user
            String studentDetails = 
            "SELECT * FROM student WHERE RegNO = '"+login.getText()+"'";
            System.out.println("Login is: " + login.getText());
    
            ps = ConnectionDatabase.DbConnection().prepareStatement(studentDetails);
            
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    
            while(rs.next())
            {     
                String fullName = rs.getString("FullName");
                String regNO = rs.getString("RegNO");
                
                studentNameLbl.setText(fullName);
                regNumberLbl.setText(regNO);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            
        }
```

**Output**

```
run:
Login is: 
Connection Established!
Connection Established!
Login is: 
Connection Established!
Username : AP003/0007/12
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)
```

Comment: [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: You probably also want to get fundamental grasp of the [model view controller](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+model+view+controller&rlz=1C5GCEM_enAU1020AU1020&oq=java+model+view+controller&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.3029j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) concept